# Change \item font in beamer's enumerate environment

Tags: beamer, enumitem, oldstylenums, liningnums

Below I'm using oldstyle numbers in the document, but I've defined a new font with lining numbers to use in enumerated lists:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Libertinus Sans}[Numbers = {OldStyle, Proportional}]
    \newfontfamily\enumfont{Libertinus Sans}[Numbers ={Lining, Monospaced}]

\usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist[enumerate]{font = \enumfont}

\begin{document}
%    \begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 12345
        \item 67890
    \end{enumerate}
%    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

With `\documentclass{article}`, the document compiles fine:

[image]

With `\documentclass{beamer}`, however, I get this error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\labelenumi ->{\labelenumi 
                           }
l.16 ^^I\end{frame}
```

I assume this has something to do with how `enumitem` and `beamer` work together, but I don't know how to fix it. So how can I use monospaced lining numbers in enumerate environments in beamer?

---

**Update**

Trying [samcarter's suggestion below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347603/9077) with `\setbeamerfont`, there's only an effect in the top level list, not in an embedded list:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}[Numbers = {OldStyle, Proportional}]
    \setbeamerfont{enumerate item}{family = {\fontspec[Numbers ={Lining, Monospaced}]{Libertinus Sans}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item foo
        \item bar
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item 123
                \item 456
                \item 789
            \end{enumerate}
        \item baz
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's known that `enumitem` is not compatible with `beamer`.

Comment: @egreg Right, but I assume it's still possible to modify the font in ``beamer``'s ``enumerate`` environment without invoking ``enumitem``?

Comment: For changing the font in general: `\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\fontsize{20}{24}}` and `\setbeamerfont{enumerate item}{series=\bfseries,size=\fontsize{20}{24}}`. But I am no expert for getting your specific font

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `enumitem` with beamer. You don't need it anyway, as using beamers font mechanism is sufficient.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{family={\fontspec[Variant=1]{Zapfino}}}
\setbeamerfont{enumerate item}{family={\fontspec[Variant=1]{Zapfino}}}
\setbeamerfont{enumerate subitem}{family={\fontspec[Variant=1]{Zapfino}}}


\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 12345
        \item 67890
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item 12345
            \item 67890
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I added `\setbeamerfont{enumerate item}{family = {\fontspec[Numbers = {Lining, Monospaced}]{Libertinus Sans}}}` to my preamble, but the line is simply ignored when compiling.

Comment: @Sverre Unfortunately I don't have the `Libertinus Sans` font so cannot test your code. Replacing it with e.g. `Zapfino` works fine.

Comment: `Libertinus` is included in `tex live`, so it should work out of the box. Please see the update to my question for the problem with an embedded list (that's why it seemed to me that the line was ignored).

Comment: @Sverre For sublist you have to set the respective templates `enumerate subitem` etc.  -- `enumerate item` will only affect the top level.